# Pandas filter through dataframe and compute stats

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to access certain categories of data and do stat computation.

```
            A         B         C   Type
0    1.539708 -1.166480  0.533026   foo
1    1.302092 -0.505754  0.533026   foo
2   -0.371983  1.104803 -0.651520   bar
3   -1.309622  1.118697 -1.161657   bar
4   -1.924296  0.396437  0.812436   baz
```

Expected output (I've left the data blank below, however the actual program will have correct output.):

```
user_input = input('Select type: ')  <-----user input foo
   Mean 25% Median
A  
B
C
```

So far I'm able to create a function to caclulate mean, 25% and median for the whole dataframe using below,

```
def stat(df):
   mean = df[['A','B','C']].mean()
   quantile = df[['A','B','C']].quantile(0.25)
   median = df[['A','B','C']].median()
   df1 = mean.rename('Mean').to_frame()
   df2 = quantile.rename('25%').to_frame()
   df3 = median.rename('Median').to_frame()
   df = df1.join([df2,df3])
   return df
```

What I'm lacking is to have the option to select particular type in column Type and still producing the same outcome as stat function. Can anyone gives hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do some [boolean indexing with `.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for the `Type` column:

```
user_input = input('Select type: ')

def stat(df, Type):
    mean = df.loc[(df['Type'] == Type), ['A','B','C']].mean()
    quantile = df.loc[(df['Type'] == Type), ['A','B','C']].quantile(0.25)
    median = df.loc[(df['Type'] == Type), ['A','B','C']].median()
    df1 = mean.rename('Mean').to_frame()
    df2 = quantile.rename('25%').to_frame()
    df3 = median.rename('Median').to_frame()
    df = df1.join([df2,df3])
    return df
```

For example, this is how it would look like if you filter row-wise if the `user_input` is `foo`

```
stat(df, user_input)

Out[1]: 
       Mean       25%    Median
A  1.420900  1.361496  1.420900
B -0.836117 -1.001298 -0.836117
C  0.533026  0.533026  0.533026
```